# Is there any way to visualize code flow in docker (or in go language)

Tags: go, docker

I started contributing to docker but faced some challenges.

- Its difficult to understand the flow of code. Is there any way to know the flow of code. Suppose I ran "docker run" is there any way or tool where I get to know what all functions are called.
- If docker don't provide any such tool then is there any similar tool for go language as docker is written in go.

Comment: This is not what yo are asking for, but it might be helpful: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_Y9xCEMj5S-7rv2ooHpZNH15JgRT5iM742gJkw5LtmQ/edit

Comment: Are you looking for a Go debugger, like Delve? https://github.com/derekparker/delve. Or does it strictly need to be graphical/visual?